# In ModelSim with verilog, can you reset the state of the simulation back to the start while continuing the simulation?

Tags: verilog, verification, modelsim

This is a very difficult question to word so I will describe what effect I desire.

Say if I have verilog code such as:

```
...
/*procedure 1 generating stimuli for module 1*/;
/*procedure 2 generating stimuli for module 1*/;
...
```

And module_thing has internal states that affect all future computation. Is there a command I can use such as 'reset_state' that will reset module_thing back to its start state?

So in verilog:

```
...
/*procedure 1 generating stimuli for module 1*/;
reset_state;
/*procedure 2 generating stimuli for module 1*/;
...
```

And in ModelSim, module_thing is appropriately 'cleared' of all values, before its second call, without the need to reset the simulation.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: does `module_thing` have a reset signal? How do you normally reset the state of `module_thing`?

Comment: You first have to understand that modules are not procedurally called like a sequence of programming language statements. ModelSim does have a restart command that resets time back to time 0, but I don't think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: If for some reason you need to reset the internal state, you can force all the internal lines back to their initial states at whatever simtime you want. However, you should go with wilcroft's suggestion of having a reset line if you need this kind of functionality from the hardware. The force suggestion only will work for simulation and would require alot of complex scripting if your design gets big.

Comment: @wilcroft module_thing does have a reset signal, however I would like to avoid using it in case the reset functionality itself is buggy. I should at this point mention I am designing a test bench for a black boxed DUV. If it is too much of a hassle to do what I am asking for should I just use the reset signal?

Comment: @dave_59 I apologise for the example. Though what you say does sound like what I am looking for as long as it can be invoked from within verilog code? So if I have gotten to line 15 with this "time back to 0" then the simulation will continue from line 16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control time from inside a Verilog description, you can only wait for it to pass, or wait for a change in signal. You are thinking like software calling a function. That is not how hardware works. And you need to think about the difference between running a simulation of a hardware description written in Verilog, versus the script that you use to invoke the simulation. A simulation always starts at time 0 and moves forward. Time 0 is when all the `initial` and `always` blocks in your description start executing statements.

The script that runs the simulation can tell the tool to run for a certain amount of simulated time, stop, then restart at time 0. But that means all the `initial` and `always` blocks in your description start executing statements all over again.